# How to validate Xades-t message when the order of the attributes in the x509SubjectName differ from the order in the certificate

Tags: xades4j

At the moment I'm trying to validate messages from a third party.
The problem I'm having is that the chain of trust can't be created.
The reason is that order of the items in the subject name (X509SubjectName) are different in the certificate as they are when you extract them from included certificate.

Per example: 
In the xades-t message the x509SubjectName tag has:
"C=NL,O=Test company,CN=testuser,SERIALNUMBER=1"
where as the x509SubjectName included in the certificate has :
"SERIALNUMBER=1,CN=testuser,O=Test company,C=NL"

My question is whether this is allowed. 
And how can I change the Xades4j behaviour to validate these signed messages.
As I don't seem to have the certificate in the SignatureUtils class. The code seems to be able to handle is but the used map is empty.

Regards,
Pim

Comment: The DN should be equivalent. Are you sure that's the cause of your problem? I can only remember of one place where DN are compared and is the issuer's DN, not the subject's.

Comment: Hi,I wrote a specific class to test the situation.

Comment: Hi,I wrote a specific class to test the situation. In one instance I got the DN from the xades message. Which fails. (Error message is that it is unable to validate the chain of trust) The second call I used the same certificate but retrieved the DN from the Certificate itself. Then I got a validator. So no exception.Therefor I printed both version of the DN. Which gave me the details above.

Comment: The problem is in the class xades4j.utils.PropertiesUtils.java.
In the method processKeyInfo if retrieves the DN from the signature.
This is then used to instantiate KeyInfo object.
Which at it's turn is used in xades4j.providers.impl.PKIXCertificateValidatinProvidor to instantiate the java.security.cert.certPathBuilder.
During this instantiation the 'wrong' DN is used to build the chain of trust.
Wrong means correct items off the DN but in the wrong order. (To be clear the certificate order is the weird one. The DN, from the xades message, order conforms to the LDAP structure)

Answer (score 1):

In RFC2253 document, section 2.1, it says:

> 2.1. Converting the RDNSequence
>
> If the RDNSequence is an empty sequence, the result is the empty or
>   zero length string.
>
> Otherwise, the output consists of the string encodings of each
>   RelativeDistinguishedName in the RDNSequence (according to 2.2),
>   starting with the last element of the sequence and moving backwards
>   toward the first.
>
> The encodings of adjoining RelativeDistinguishedNames are separated
>   by a comma character (',' ASCII 44).

So, whatever the sequence is, you need to reverse the order. Therefore, I think you should first check your implementation and make sure you reverse the sequence of the Relative Distinguished Names.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I think this is the cause of the problem. However a change is required in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround by changing the xades4j behaviour.

As I have not found any documentation that the order of the attribute in the X509SubjectName need to be identical as in the order of the DN in the associated Certificate. I think the following patch is required for robustness.

In case the *xades4j.verification.SignatureUtil.java* decides to rely on the subjectname. It should not just continue using it, but should verify whether the subjectname is identical to the subjectname in the certificate. This can't be done by comparing the complete string. Instead both subject names need to be unmashalled and be compared based on their associated.

First the selection behaviour needs to changed a little:
Instead of just using the subjectname, first retrieve the DN from the certificate and then compare their values. If they don't match using the complete string, they should could match on their actual content. Therefor we need to get the attributes of both DN's. When no differences are found we are still dealing with the same DN. 
In this case the framework cannot rely on the subjectname to retrieve the certificate from the certificate store. Instead give the certificate to the KeyInfo object. (That will be found!)

```
        if (x509Data.containsIssuerSerial()) {
            issuerSerial = x509Data.itemIssuerSerial(0);
            certSelector.setIssuer(new X500Principal(issuerSerial.getIssuerName()));
            certSelector.setSerialNumber(issuerSerial.getSerialNumber());
        } else if (x509Data.containsSubjectName()) {
            String subjectName = x509Data.itemSubjectName(0).getSubjectName();
            X500Principal msgPrincipal = new X500Principal(subjectName);
            String name = msgPrincipal.getName();

            X509Certificate crt = x509Data.itemCertificate(0).getX509Certificate();
            X500Principal crtPrincipal = crt.getSubjectX500Principal();

            X500Principal prinFromCrt = crt.getSubjectX500Principal();
            if(prinFromCrt.getName().equals(msgPrincipal.getName())){
                // Continue using the xades specified subjectname
                 certSelector.setSubject(msgPrincipal);
            } else {
                //so the subject names are not equal.
                //However the ietf specifications indicate you cannot rely on the order of the attributed.
                //Therefor we need to compare all attributes seperately to know for sure.

               boolean hasSameKeyValues = compareUnmarshelledX500PrincipalAttr(crtPrincipal,msgPrincipal);
               if (hasSameKeyValues){

                   if (x509Data.containsCertificate()) {
                       certSelector.setCertificate(x509Data.itemCertificate(0).getX509Certificate());
                   }
               }    
            }

        } else if (x509Data.containsCertificate()) {
            certSelector.setCertificate(x509Data.itemCertificate(0).getX509Certificate());
            if (x509Data.containsSubjectName()){
                //if(!(isEqualX500Elements(new X500Principal(x509Data.itemSubjectName(0).getSubjectName()), x509Data.itemCertificate(0).getX509Certificate()))){
                //     throw new InvalidKeyInfoDataException("X509Subject name differs from Subject name in certificate.");
                //}
            }
        } else
        // No criteria to select the leaf certificate.
        // Improvement: search the SigningCertiticate property and try to
        // find the "bottom" certificate.
        {
            throw new InvalidKeyInfoDataException("No criteria to select the leaf certificate");
        }
```

Below is a method which takes the DN's and request for a HashMap containing the keys and their values.
It will return just a boolean whether they are identical or not.

```
       private static boolean compareUnmarshelledX500PrincipalAttr(X500Principal DN1, X500Principal DN2) {
       HashMap attrDNCrt = splitDNAttr(DN1.getName());
       HashMap attrDNMsg = splitDNAttr(DN2.getName());

       if(attrDNCrt.keySet().equals(attrDNMsg.keySet())){
           Set ks = attrDNCrt.keySet();
           Iterator iKS = ks.iterator();
           while (iKS.hasNext()){
               String key = (String) iKS.next();
               if(!attrDNCrt.get(key).toString().equals(attrDNMsg.get(key).toString())){
                   //Value of attribute is different. So not identical
                   return false;
               }
           }
           //Yes, despite possible differences in order the key value pairs are identical.");
           return true;
       } else {
           //"KeySets differ so they are different"
           return false;
       }
}
```

The splitDNAttr will rely on the fact the key namings won't contain ','. Therefor I first split on '=' and then on the last ','. 
There propably are regexp outthere which also do the trick. (Unfortunately RegEx are completely unreadable for me.)
The methods works for me but I wonder whether I need to remove possible trailing spaces"?

```
static private HashMap splitDNAttr(String inputStr){
    String[] strings;
    List looseElements;
    looseElements = new ArrayList();
    //First split on the = which normally isn't escaped.
    strings = inputStr.split("=");        
    looseElements.add(strings[0]);
    //Loop Through string members

    int i=1;
    while (i<strings.length){
        String[] subStrings;
        //Look for the last comma, everything after is a key! This is because we have splitted the string on '='
        int splitPos = strings[i].lastIndexOf(",");
        if(splitPos>=0){
            //Add all found items to a list. Order must be maintained!
            String A = strings[i].substring(0,splitPos);
            looseElements.add(strings[i].substring(0,splitPos));
            String B = strings[i].substring(splitPos+1);
            looseElements.add(strings[i].substring(splitPos+1));
        } else {
            looseElements.add(strings[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    // Put key and values in a HashMap
    HashMap dnAttr = new HashMap();
    Iterator iLooseElements;
    iLooseElements = looseElements.iterator();
    String a;
    String b;
    while(iLooseElements.hasNext()){
        a = (String) iLooseElements.next();
        b = (String) iLooseElements.next();
        dnAttr.put(a, b);
    }
    return dnAttr;
}
```